# How to uninstall Jupyter Notebook and related dependencies installed on WSL via Anaconda?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

Like every day, I entered the `jupyter notebook` command on my WSL terminal to operate on some ipynb files and this is what the browser gives me:

[image]

I tried a few times from different folders, in new sessions of WSL and still the same. Some googling vaguely tells me to simply uninstall jupyter and re-install it. I installed jupyter notebook via CONDA on the WSL, and now I am unable to uninstall it.

Here is some info:

```
the_piranha@LAPTOP-VENAQQDC:~/projects$ which -a jupyter
/home/the_piranha/anaconda3/bin/jupyter
```

I have tried uninstalling it like this:

```
the_piranha@LAPTOP-VENAQQDC:~/projects$ conda remove jupyter jupyter-client jupyter-console jupyter-core
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - jupyter-client
  - jupyter-console
  - jupyter-core
```

So now I am unable to uninstall and still stuck with the command not working issue as in the image above.

Comment: Have you tried `conda remove jupyter*`?

Comment: I thought `conda remove jupyter jupyter-client jupyter-console jupyter-core` ought to cover this. But I ran just `conda remove jupyter` on your suggestion, and for past 1 hour, the command seems to be just running. A lot of libraries have been uninstalled, and some are now being installed at the moment! Let's see what happens.

Comment: That got stuck and I had to end the session after 2 hours. I tried `conda remove jupyterlab`. This worked, and I reinstalled it by `conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab`. However, the issue in the image is still there!